# FirebaseUI/Auth with Email-Password

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm hoping to use FirebaseUI/Auth with Facebook, Google, and email/password authentication options.

On [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseUI) page, it shows how to add Google and Facebook providers:

```
FIRGoogleAuthUI *googleAuthUI =
[[FIRGoogleAuthUI alloc] initWithClientID:kGoogleClientID];
FIRFacebookAuthUI *facebookAuthUI =
[[FIRFacebookAuthUI alloc] initWithAppID:kFacebookAppID];
authUI.providers = @[ googleAuthUI, facebookAuthUI];
```

How would I add email-password to the auth providers option and have it appear on `authViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/71) is the answer I got from the FirebaseUI Github page:

Email-password is enabled as a sign-in option by default, it doesn't require any configuration :)

A "Sign in with email" option should appear on `authViewController`, unless `signInWithEmailHidden` is set to `YES`.